# Insert PHP variables into CURL XML post

Tags: php, xml, curl

i'm a bit stuck here and would be really thankful if someone could point me in the right direction :)

i'm posting "unauth" value from a form and retrieving it fine. What i'd like to do is to insert it into the XML that i'm posting as a variable. The variable would need to be inserted in the macAddress field. Here's what I have in mind

macAddress="**$unauth**" (Line 8)

```
<?php 
  session_start();
$unauth = $_POST['unauth'];
$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TipsApiRequest xmlns="http://www.avendasys.com/tipsapiDefs/1.0">
<TipsHeader version="3.0"/>
<Endpoints>
<Endpoint status="Known" macAddress="$unauth">
<EndpointTags tagName="unauthorized" tagValue="true"/>
</Endpoint>
</Endpoints>
</TipsApiRequest>';
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://x.x.x.x/tipsapi/config/write/Endpoint");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$output2 = curl_exec($c);

if($output2 === false)
{
trigger_error('Erreur curl : '.curl_error($c),E_USER_WARNING);
}
else
{`enter code here`
var_dump($output2);
var_dump($_POST);
}
curl_close($c);
?>
```

Here's the XML response I get

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><TipsApiResponse xmlns="http://www.avendasys.com/tipsapiDefs/1.0"><TipsHeader exportTime="Mon Jan 25 20:10:18 GMT 2016" version="6.5"/><StatusCode>Success</StatusCode><TipsApiError><ErrorCode>InvalidXml</ErrorCode><Message>Endpoint MAC Address "&amp;#x24;unauth" is invalid</Message></TipsApiError></TipsApiResponse>
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using simple quotes `'` in the XML string construction. Inside the simple quotes, the variables aren't interpreted. You must encapsulate your XML string inside double quotes `"` or concat the variable in your string.

```
<?php
$s = 'a string';
echo '$s'; // Show $s
echo "$s"; // Show a string
```

Example on your string with concatenation :

```
$unauth = 'attribute value';
$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TipsApiRequest xmlns="http://www.avendasys.com/tipsapiDefs/1.0">
    <TipsHeader version="3.0"/>
    <Endpoints>
        <Endpoint status="Known" macAddress="'.$unauth.'">
            <EndpointTags tagName="unauthorized" tagValue="true"/>
        </Endpoint>
    </Endpoints>
</TipsApiRequest>';
```

You can also use [HEREDOC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string construction which interprete variables inside :

```
$unauth = 'attribute value';
$xml_data = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TipsApiRequest xmlns="http://www.avendasys.com/tipsapiDefs/1.0">
    <TipsHeader version="3.0"/>
    <Endpoints>
        <Endpoint status="Known" macAddress="$unauth">
            <EndpointTags tagName="unauthorized" tagValue="true"/>
        </Endpoint>
    </Endpoints>
</TipsApiRequest>
XML;
```

Also you must validate POST data using the [PHP filters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) function to avoid code injection in your XML request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to respond and explain. Works #1 :D :D !!